# Android : how to launch two activities

Tags: android

I have  Three pages Splash_Activity , Login_Activity, Activity_One

The activity flow is Splash_Activity -> Login_Activity -> Activity_One .In that case i check the .db file is exist or not in my Splash_Activity which is always start activity of application.

**I put the condition for if .db is exist then go to Activity_One** 
**and if not then go to Login_Activity .**

But the problem when i delete .db file on button click the .db file is deleted properly and display the login page.

When i exist the app without login and I again start the app first two three times run and check the .db file is not available then go to login page but after that it goes to Activity_One. Why this happen

This splash screen

```
public class Splash_Screen  extends RootActivity
{
    MyDbHelper dbhelper ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_page);

        Thread loading = new Thread() {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    File database=getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("ClassNKK.db");

                    if (!database.exists()) {
                        // Database does not exist so copy it from assets here
                        Log.i("Database", "Not Found");
                        try
                        {
                            sleep(2000);
                            Intent main = new Intent(Splash_Screen.this, Login_Screen.class);
                            startActivity(main);
                            Log.e("DB "," is null !!!");
                        }

                        catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        Log.i("Database", "Found");
                        try {
                            sleep(2000);
                            Intent main = new Intent(Splash_Screen.this, AllPosts_Page.class);
                            startActivity(main);
                            Log.e("DB ", " is null !!!");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                   } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

        loading.start();
    }

}
```

And this logout button on Activity_One page

```
 imgBtn_LogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(dbhelper.DATABASE_NAME);

                if (!database.exists()) {
                    Log.e("Database", "Not Found");
                } else {
                    Log.e("Database", "Found");
                    ctx.deleteDatabase(dbhelper.DATABASE_NAME);
                    Log.e("Database", " Deleted Completeley !!!");

                    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "classnkk_images");
                    DeleteRecursive(dir);

                    Intent i = new Intent(Filter_Screen.this, Login_Screen.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: when you press logout button what is your logcat output??? Does it output "Log.e("Database", "Found");" and " Log.e("Database", " Deleted Completeley !!!");"

Comment: Log.e("Database", " Deleted Completeley !!!");"

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you start application after delete db, it will automatically create new database without data.

So please check again database had created or not ?

I suggest you to save parameter in share preference and check it when in splash screen. It better!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store login credential you can use sharedPreference instead of sqlite. I think it will be most suitable method for this.

http://androidforbegineers.blogspot.in/2013/08/shared-preference-using-registration.html

this blog will help you.:)